# Angular 2 unit testing with ngModel

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, angular-cli

I am using the latest angular-cli with angular 2.1. The component test I want to write is simple: Get some data from a service and display it.

It works, when the data ist simply displayed in a paragraph, but it does not, when it is bound to a textarea.

Below is an excerpt from my template:

```
<p *ngIf="!isBusy" class="twain">
  <i>{{settings.blockLoginMessage}}</i>
</p>
<textarea  
  id="blockLoginMessage" 
  name="blockLoginMessage" 
  [(ngModel)]="settings.blockLoginMessage" 
  class="form-control">
</textarea>
```

and the corresponding tests:

```
describe('SettingsComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [SharedModule, TranslateModule.forRoot()],
            declarations: [SettingsComponent],
            providers: [
                Overlay,
                ToastsManager,
                ViewContainerRef,
                TranslateService,
                SettingsService
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SettingsComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;

        settingsService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SettingsService);

        getSettingsSpy = spyOn(settingsService, 'getSettings')
            .and.returnValue(Observable.of(new Settings(true, false, 'test')).delay(500).toPromise());

        setSettingsSpy = spyOn(settingsService, 'setSettings')
            .and.returnValue(Observable.of(true).delay(500));

        fixture.detectChanges(); 
    });

    it('should create the component', () => {
        expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should show busy indicator as long as there are no settings', () => {
        let busyPanel = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#busyPanel'));
        expect(busyPanel).not.toBeNull('cant find busy');
    });

    it('should show loaded settings after observable finished (done)', done => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        // get the spy promise and wait for it to resolve
        getSettingsSpy.calls.mostRecent().returnValue.then(() => {
            fixture.detectChanges();

            let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.twain'));
            let el = de.nativeElement;

            expect(el.textContent).toBe('test', 'show loaded settings');

            let de2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#blockLoginMessage'));
            let el2: HTMLTextAreaElement = de2.nativeElement;

            expect(el2.textContent).toBe('test', 'show loaded settings');

            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Does anyone have a hint why this does not work?

Furthermore, my attempts with `async` and `fakeAsync` fail completely, when I have a delay in my promises like above.

Comment: fixture.isStable() returns false btw

Comment: Can you post a complete example, preferably just using a dummy component, and service, all posted in one page we can copy and paste and test as is. And please include only what is necessary to reproduce the problem (i.e. no translate module) or anything else that doesn't involve solving the problem of how to test ngModel. This is what an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is

Comment: pls check [Angular 2 Testing: Get Value from ngModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983135/angular-2-testing-get-value-from-ngmodel)

Answer (score 8):

`ngModel` updates asynchronously since RC5. You should test it asynchronous way:

```
it('should check initial value of ngModel', async(() => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    let el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select your input'));
    let actual = selectElement.nativeElement.value;
    expect(expected).toBe(actual);
  });
}));
```

Comment: BTW here is the link to CHANGELOG changes that describe it - https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f444c11d218d26ac817d5f3b12e19c6b4b8d2390

Comment: Thank you so much. This should be upvoted a thousand times more