# Angular 2 Testing: Get Value from ngModel

Tags: angular

I'm trying to write a test that asserts on Angular's `ngModel` attribute. At this point, I can easily test the label. However, I am not able to select the value from `ngModel`

> **Question** What is the best way to get the value from `ngModel`?

**HTML:**

```
<div name="customerName">
    <label>Customer Name: </label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="customer.name" asInline disabled />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Test**

```
it('bindings', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomerComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // this works
    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[name=customerName] label').textContent).toEqual('Customer Name: '); 
    // this assert fails
    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[name=customerName] div input').value).toEqual('Bobby Tables'); 
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `async` together with `whenStable`

```
it('should recognize a timepicker', async(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[name=customerName] label').textContent).toEqual('Customer Name: ');

    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[name=customerName] div input').value).toEqual('Bobby Tables');
  });   
}));
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/hdCQPI9ruyRJEByR7P46?p=preview)**

or `fakeAsync` with `tick`:

```
it('should recognize a timepicker', fakeAsync(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[name=customerName] label').textContent).toEqual('Customer Name: ');

  expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[name=customerName] div input').value).toEqual('Bobby Tables');
}));
```

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VFu3JYfGqLvBNISY70mP?p=preview)

And don't forget to import `FormsModule`:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [FormsModule],
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't resolve my problem. The `.value` is returning an empty string. If I log it at the `[name=customerName] div input` level, I get  `<input asinline="" class="form-control" disabled="" type="text">`. I've verified, and my component has the correct data. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I've got it working, needed to add the `imports: [FormsModule]` to my `beforeEach` Thank you!